# Strange leaks detected by Instruments with no stack (505 x 64 bytes __NSMallocBlock__)

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, instruments

During development of my App I am doing my regular leak detection tests using Instruments.  A new set of leaks has been detected with no stack information available. They total 505 blocks of 64 bytes containing various bits of information:

[image]

The *Leak Contents* in the top-right translates to:

```
registerInterface: Frequent transitions for interface en1 (192.1
```

This text does not appear in my program and my MBP is on the 192.168.0.0 network, so it looks like live system data.  The other leaked blocks contain different information (some all `0xff` and some containing fragments of ASCII and other assorted binary).

I think this leak has been unfairly attributed to my program, especially as no stack trace is available.  Has anyone else seen this and know of a fix?

- OSX Version: 10.8.2
- Instruments Version: 4.6

Comment: I should mention that these leaks are no longer appear since transitioning to ARC.